# Python working with hostnames, hostname to IP

Tags: python, string, sockets

In python I need to get IP from hostname:

```
socket.gethostbyname('www.python.org') # returns ip good
socket.gethostbyname('http://python.org') # raises error
```

I need to deal with hostnames starting with 'http://' so I figured out a way to remake them like this:

```
a = 'http://python.org'
a.replace('http://', 'www.')
print a # Why does it print http://python.org ???
```

I'm not sure I do the right thing. Plz help me with translating this type of hostname to IP

Comment: What is `b`? It should be `a.replace('http://', 'www.')`

Comment: Also your idea is wrong, you should replace `http://` with an empty string. `www.python.org` might point to a different IP than `python.org`.

Comment: You are editing a and printing b?

Comment: sry, my fault in this example. in code it's really a. But still not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want `urlparse`:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> urlparse.urlparse('http://python.org')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='python.org', path='', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse.urlparse('http://python.org').netloc
'python.org'
>>>
```

Oh, and yes, you don't need to add any "www" in front of the top-level domain.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this,

```
a = 'http://python.org'
a = a.replace('http://', 'www.')  
# a.replace() does not change the original string. it returns a new string (replaced version).
print a
```

Answer (score -1):

You have several problems.

1st. Error is raised, because `http://stuff` is not a valid domain. It is natural to expect an error.

2nd. `b` does not exists in the context you provided.

3rd. It is a dangerous thing to swap `http://` for `www.` blindly. `python.org` and `www.python.org` are two different domains and they may point to different places!

You should use regular expressions or some other routines to extract the domain name from an URL, and use `gethostbyname` on it.